# Functions assigned to per number of click / click count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below script setup. I would like to better rewrite the script to which the the functions are assigned more specific to per click, `EG. Click = 3 does so and so, and Click = 4, does this and that.`

**EDIT**: For example, you can view my live sample at 'http://bit.ly/10BW89N' notice, the Clicks done fire in order. I've added a simple 'alert' to try and test it, and the clicks and functions still don't fire in proper order.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a1_Events = [function1, function2, function3, function5, function6, function7, function8],
        a1_c = 0;
    function function1() {
        alert('SHAKING!');
    }
    function function2() {
        alert('BZZZZZZZZZZZ!');
    }
    function function3() {
        $("#area1").hide();
        $("#area2").show();
    }
    function function5() {
        alert('YES!');
    }
    function function6() {
        $("#bg_div").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#bg_skew").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
    }
    function function7() {
        alert('NO!');
    }
    function function8() {
        $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#sound1").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
    }
    $('#area1').click(function () {
        a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_Events.length]();
    });
    $("#area2").click(function () {
        $("#area1").show();
        $("#area2").hide();
    });
});
```

**..any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JavaScript `switch` statement in combination with some jQuery functions like so to simplify your code and do what you want it to:

```
 //global userClicks variable holds count of user clicks
 var userClicks = 0;     

 //Standard jQuery click function to catch the user clicks       
 $('#area1').click(function () {

        //code to increment clicks here...
        userClicks+=1;

        //call the below function with the switch statement and execution code
        callSwitch(userClicks);

 });

   //the JavaScript function which takes the number of clicks as a parameter
   function callSwitch(numClicks){

      //switch statement based on parameter passed to enclosing function
      switch (numClicks) 
        {
        case 1:
          alert('SHAKING!');
          break; 

        case 2:
           alert('BZZZZZZZZZZZ!');
           break;

        case 3:
          $("#area1").hide();
          $("#area2").show();
          break;

        case 5:
          alert('YES!');
          break;

        case 6:
          $("#bg_div").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
          $("#bg_skew").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
          break;

        case 7:
          alert('NO!');
          break;

        case 8:
          $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
          $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
          $("#sound1").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
          break;
        }
   }
```

[**Here is my JSFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/rrDSd/) for an example implementation of this.

You could also still keep the functions separate as you have in your implementation and just call them from each conditional `case` block as needed like so:

```
switch (numClicks) 
          {
            case 1:
              function1();
              break;        
            case 2:
               function2();
               break;
            case 3:
              function3();
              break;
          }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a1_c = 0, a1_Events = {
        0: function() {
               alert('SHAKING!');
           },
        1: function() {
               alert('BZZZZZZZZZZZ!');
           },
        2: function() {
               $("#area1").hide();
               $("#area2").show();
           },
        3: function() {
               alert('YES!');
           },
        4: function() {
               $("#bg_div").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
               $("#bg_skew").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
           },
        5: function() {
               alert('NO!');
           },
        6: function() {
               $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
               $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
               $("#sound1").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
           }
    }, a1_EventCount = Object.keys(a1_Events).length; // or hard-code 7.

    $('#area1').click(function () {
        a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_EventCount]();
    });

    $("#area2").click(function () {
        $("#area1").show();
        $("#area2").hide();
    });
});
```

If you are in an environment without `Object.keys` and you don't want to shim it, you can simply hard-code the event count, although you will have to remember to change it if you add or remove events.

This will work much like the array for indexed access, but lets you explicitly assign the specific functions to the particular values.